# Sending an image from a C# client to a C server

Tags: c#, c, sockets

If I send plain text there is no problem. Everything is ok.
However If I try to send from the C# client an image, the server receives correct bytes number, but when I save the buffer to a file (in binary mode - wb), it always has 4 bytes.

I send it by the C# client by using the function `File.ReadAllBytes()`.

My saving code looks like

```
   FILE * pFile;
   char *buf = ReceiveMessage(s);
   pFile = fopen (fileName , "wb");
   fwrite(buf, sizeof(buf[0]), sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]), pFile);
   fclose (pFile);
   free(buf);
```

My receiving function looks like

```
static unsigned char *ReceiveMessage(int s)
{
   int prefix;
   recv(s, &prefix, 4, 0);
   int len = prefix;
   char *buffer= (char*)malloc(len + 1);
   int received = 0, totalReceived = 0;
   buffer[len] = '\0';
   while (totalReceived < len)
   {
      if (len - totalReceived > BUFFER_SIZE)
      {
         received = recv(s, buffer + totalReceived, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      }
      else
      {
         received = recv(s, buffer + totalReceived, len - totalReceived, 0);
      }
      totalReceived += received;
   }

   return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C code needs to pass `len` back from the ReceiveMessage() function.

```
char *buf = ReceiveMessage(s);  // buf is a char*
... sizeof(buff)                // sizeof(char*) is 4 or 8
```

So you'll need something like

```
 static unsigned char *ReceiveMessage(int s, int* lenOut)
 {
     ...
     *lenOut = totalReceived ;
 }
```

Comment: Why can't I use `strlen(buf)` instead of?

Comment: Bescause `strlen()` is for strings and will only count upto the first `'\0'`

Answer (score 1):

You do a beginners mistake of using `sizeof(buf)`. It doesn't return the number of bytes in the buffer but the size of the pointer (which is four or eight depending on if you run 32 or 64 bit platform).

You need to change the `ReceiveMessage` function to also "return" the size of the received data.

Comment: Why can't I use `strlen(buf)` instead of?

Comment: @daroPL You can, but only if the received data is in fact a proper string. If it's an image it contains binary data which can contain a byte with value `0` which is used as a string terminator.

Answer (score 1):

You do not get size of array by `sizeof`. Change to i.e.:

```
int len = 0;
char *buf;

buf = ReceiveMessage(s, &len);

/* then use len to calculate write length */


static unsigned char *ReceiveMessage(int s, int *len) 
/* or return len and pass ptr to buf */
{


  ...
}
```